# how to rename SSRS subscription job to a propper name

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created some SSRS subscription which is generating as `UNIQUE ID(GUID)` in `msdb.dbo.sysjobs`. 
But now i want to rename these IDs to a proper name which will easy for maintenance.

I tried to rename the job name, steps of job and it's working properly.

Problem is that, again, this auto job has created (with GUID) for all the subscription.

This is the reason, two jobs are firing for same report , one from propername job and one from GUID job.

Please see below

[image]

Comment: Hi @user1818042 do you have admin rights...?

Comment: Hi Andy , Yes i have admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do this. Maintain all subscriptions through Report Manager, or SharePoint if you reports are hosted on SP. Sure, you can change the name of the job, but the minute you change the subscription, the job will be replaced.

If you want to be able to run subscriptions by hand, try make sure that the schedules vary enough from one to the other so you can identify them by when they run.

Messing with these jobs will only cause you pain the likes of which you do not want to experience. Just come to terms with it. Life is better that way.

Comment: That was going to be my reply but then I got to thinking... What if you accepted that you would never maintain them using the GUI? I reckon the whole thing would be easier to manage through SQL once you had ditched the GUID - I wonder if anyone has ever created a view so that you can SELECT * FROM... Could be a new project!

Comment: The view idea sounds like a good one, no doubt. Without the GUI, are you creating new subscriptions/jobs with SSRS stored procedures? Not the worst, but certainly not the best way to go. Do you think there's a market/need for a new subscription UI? That could be fun!

Comment: We often have to insert a step prior to the subscription step to enable the use of conditional SQL. As other have stated you just have to accept that once it is created in the GUI you can not edit it in that way.