# Rename Job created by Subscription in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have created some SSRS subscription which is generating as UNIQUE
 ID(GUID) in msdb.dbo.sysjobs. But now I want to rename these IDs to a proper name which will easy for maintenance.

[image]

I renamed the job and never change anything in the subscription but I can see everyday early morning (8.51 AM) all the auto jobs is generating in Sql agent with GUID.

And I received 2 emails.

Is there any way I can rename it and next time when Subscription run it should not generate new Job?

Comment: Can you define what 'auto jobs' mean? I have tried to reproduce the issue by creating a subscription, renaming the job and I see it's working perfectly fine. I even auto-scheduled it to run 5 minute interval after my changes, it's working as expected. Even under 'Subscriptions' of the report I see the run log.

Comment: It will only works fine the day subscription is created ,.But when it run next day it create a new one.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139300/how-to-rename-ssrs-subscription-job-to-a-propper-name)

Answer (score 0):

Do have a look at Richard's thread. It will throw some light. I have to tell even in my machine another subscription with new GUID got generated. Lesson here is one should not be interfering with the system generated subscription names. If you do want to be able to do maintenance run a script on the ReportServer database and get all the details you need from it.

Here is a link that gives a good explanation - [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1846/how-to-easily-identify-a-scheduled-sql-server-reporting-services-report/)